# help to identify the component

Tags: identification, components, repair, motherboard

I don't understand what component it is (0k=g9w), and it needs to be replaced.  I've done various searches, but I can't figure it out. This is a motherboard from an Asus computer.

[image]

Comment: How do you know it needs to be replaced, if you don't even know what it is or what it does? Seems like a bit of a stretch to me. If the component is getting hot, that may indicate problems elsewhere and not necessarily with the component itself. If you buy any replacements, make sure to get a few more than just one. If you swap it out and the problem persists, it's likely you'll just damage the replacement as well.

Comment: Thank you, I connected the board to the power supply and in fact the component that I was told was faulty seems to work without overheating, checking the rest there is this one that becomes really hot

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a supervisor in a SOT-23 package: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ABLIC/S-80960CNMC-G9W-T2?qs=SvbXhG330w734Vyfpey89g%3D%3D

Answer (score 1):

It is a [RT9742CGJ5](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT9742/DS9742-10.pdf) from RICHTEK.

0K= is the product code, G9W is a date code.

picture from [LCSC](https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/RichtekTech-RT9742CGJ5/C250546):
[image]